# Spring internationalization error HTTP status 500

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to make same i18n in my webapp but i got some exception, and I dont know why, i checked twice all files and i can not see any error ;/

I try to google it, and someone says that it can be some problem in tiles.xml but I dont know where ;/

The error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: java.io.IOException: JSPException including path '/WEB-INF/views/header.jsp'.
>   Blockquote

Here is my ***servlet-context.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's 
request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently 
serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <!--Don't add suffix or prefix like you do with .jsp files-->
    <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer" >
    <beans:property name="definitions" value="/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/tiles.xml"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers 
to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<!--  Internacjonalizacja -->
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:messages/messages"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<interceptors>
    <beans:bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>   
</interceptors>

<beans:bean id="localResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="en"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="pl.projekt.mwis.controller" />
```

Here is ***header.jsp***

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>


<div >
<h3><spring:message code="label.userList"/></h3>
<span style="float: right">
    <a href="?lang=pl">pl</a> | <a href="?lang=en">en</a> | <a href="?
lang=de">de</a>
</span>
</div>
```

And Here is my ***tiles.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC 
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN" 
    "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">  

<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="base.definition"
    template="/WEB-INF/views/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/views/menu.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="user" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="User" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/user.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="home" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Home" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="hello" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Hello" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp" />
</definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

And here is my project

[image]

Here is full stack trace : https://pastebin.com/sUHz2jNs

Comment: please post full stack trace

Comment: Done, there is screen of tree of my project and there is link to full stack trace

Comment: The key thing from the stack trace - `No message found under code 'label.userList' for locale 'pl'`. Lokks like your ..._pl.properties file does not have the key. Or the file cannot be detected.

Comment: yeah i know that but file is in folder /scr/main/webapp/resources/messages
and there is field called label.userList

Comment: Ok i found my mistake, i have bad link to file idk why it should be in scr/main/resources and its work